# Blocking Graphics.drawImage

Tags: java, graphics

I'm using Graphics2D.drawImage to draw an image into a BufferedImage.
Then I Use ImageIO.write() to output this to a PNG. Often I don't see certain images that I painted this way.

I assume this is because drawImage is an asynchronous operation and I need to wait for it to complete. I've tried implementing an ImageObserver but without success.

Can anybody show me how it's done ?

Comment: You should post a small sample that clarifies your question. If the original code is too big, or it is proprietary and you don't want to release it on the net, create a tiny sample application that exhibits the problem and edit your question to include the sample. That will allow others to help in debugging. Especially, how are you implementing the ImageObserver? Perhaps your general approach is correct, but you have a tiny bug you have overlooked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.awt.MediaTracker` is a relatively easy way to make sure that an image has loaded.